# CentOS 6.4, hibernate issue

Tags: centos, hibernate, acpi

The problem is, I can't use Hibernate feature. The system allows me to, but just after the power down, the system wakes up. Seems the system is getting wakeup command from somewhere else, USB, PCI...

I tried disabling all options related to wake up on LAN, PCI, USB etc.. in CMOS settings, but everything went futile.

I'm using, Lenovo ThinkCentre M58 (7630) - simple work machine and not a server, with CentOS 6.4. No additional hardwares or anything fancy.

If you want to take a look at the `/var/log/messages`, see here

> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EJryqTUb

And from `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`

> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: **sched policy
>   powersave OFF success.

Also, see `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` here,

> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VUqAZ8KB

From the log you can see, just  two seconds after hibernating (CPU power LED goes OFF), the system came awake. If I cut the power off in between the hibernate and restart, there is no problem. i.e, System will resume nice and cool when I power it on later.

Any idea?

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Your question is more likely to get an answer here since [sf] is about managing professional systems. I suggest you delete your question there.

Comment: Post deleted from SF. Seems no one interested in here though!

Comment: Is there anything relevant in any of `/var/log/pm-suspend`, /var/log/pm-powersave.log` or `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Nothing much from pm-powersave.log. Please see the question updated with the log details.